# Match everything inbetween two tags with Regular Expressions?

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

How can I match (PCRE) everything inbetween two tags?

I tried something like this:

> <!--\s*LoginStart\s*-->(.*)<!--\s*LoginEnd\s*-->

But it didn't work out too well for me..

I'm kind of new to regular expressions, so I was hoping if someone would be kind enough to explain to me how I would accomplish this, if its even possible with regular expressions.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$string = '<!-- LoginStart --><div id="stuff">text</div><!-- LoginEnds -->';
$regex = '#<!--\s*LoginStart\s*-->(.*?)<!--\s*LoginEnds\s*-->#s';

preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches); // $matches[1] = <div id="stuff">text</div>
```

explanations:

```
(.*?) = non greedy match (match the first <!-- LoginEnds --> it finds
    s = modifier in $regex (end of the variable) allows multiline matches
        such as '<!-- LoginStart -->stuff
                 more stuff
                 <!-- LoginEnds -->'
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP and regex?  Here's some suggestions:

```
'/<!--\s*LoginStart\s*-->(.*)<!--\s*LoginEnd\s*-->/Us'
```

Might be better - the `U` capitalized makes the regex non-greedy, which means it'll stop at the first `<!--` that may work.  But the important one is the `s`, which tells the regex to match a newline with the `.` character.

Depending on how certain you are on the capitalization, adding an `i` at the end will make the regex search case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried Owen's answer but its fails for the conditions like

`<!-- LoginStart --><div id="stuff">text</div><!-- LoginEnds -->"DONT MIND THIS"<!-- LoginStart --><div id="stuff">text</div><!-- LoginEnds -->`

This includes the line "DONT MIND THIS" also, that is it covers all the contents within first
<!-- LoginStart --> and last <!-- LoginEnds --> tag