# Regular expression to match all content between 2 tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to capture the following content in PHP using regular expressions:

> /*
>
> Name: Test
>
> Description: my test
>
> */

I have tried the code from here: [Match everything inbetween two tags with Regular Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287991/match-everything-inbetween-two-tags-with-regular-expressions) but it doesnt capture the new lines.

EDIT: I used the following regular which works on a single line but it stops working as soon as it sees a line break

EDIT2: I want to include that I am running this script on a large piece of text which has a lot of line breaks. I am sure we need to use * because I am unsure of the number of line-break occurrences.

> /*(.*?)*/

TIA

Comment: Show your used regex. Also, do you mean to capture with the /* comment */ thingys as anchors?

Comment: @mario Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my original post. Yes, I want to use them as anchors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ok. The dot `.` in regular expressions does not match newlines per default. You need the /s modifier (**after the regex end**):

```
 preg_match("#/[*](.*?)[*]/#s", ...
```

Also see above, you need to escape the `*` (with a backslash or surrounding []) and if you want to match `/` you also need another character to enclose it in. I've used # instead of /

When in doubt, always add `/ims`. It's no performance drain when you don't use `^ $` or `.` and letters anyway.

Comment: Don't you mean `\/[*](.*?)[*]\/`?

Comment: Great thanks. It seems to work. I would like to know, what is #? Also, I can't seem to find any documentation on /ims as you mentioned - is it a PHP thing?

Comment: "#" is equivalent to "/". You can use ANY character to enclose regular expressions within. #ims or /ims is just a combination of /i for case-insensitive, and /m for multi-line match and /s for capturing newlines with the dot. It's a difficult topic, so I'd suggest http://www.regular-expressions.info/ which has a very good introduction for PHP preg_match too.

Comment: @Alec: No, it works without escaping here. That's why I used # enclosures. Only if you want to use regular slash enclosing style /.../i you have to escape the slashes then.

Comment: Thanks a lot mario! Learned something new today

Comment: @mario, good to know, thanks! Definitely reads a lot easier than \/\/\/s :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the flag `s` (s stands for dotall)

```
/*(.*?)*/s
```

This flag lets the dot also match newline-characters(without this flag it would'nt)

Comment: I have tried: /*(.*?)[\s]*/*\/ but it doesn't seem to work. I have updated the original post with a better example

Comment: Take a  look at http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php , (sorry, I should better call it modifier instead of flag )