# How do i match content between particular all <li> tags?

Tags: php, regex

How do I match all the <li> tags in the below HTML code:

```
<ul>
<li> some content</li>
<li> some other content</li>
<li> some other other content.</li>
</ul>
```

This expression doesn't work:

<li>(.*)</li>

Because it returns:

```
some content</li>
    <li> some other content</li>
    <li> some other other content.
```

Which is the content between the first <li> and the last </li>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match all content between 2 tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048002/regular-expression-to-match-all-content-between-2-tags)

Comment: Don't use a regular expression, use a DOM parser. All of the regex answers given so far will fail on something like `<li><ul><li>text</li></ul></li>`.

Comment: [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regular expressions are greedy by nature. Make it non-greedy by adding the `?`.

```
<li>(.*?)</li>
```

**Note:** I'd encourage a DOM Parser for such a thing. Check out [PHP's DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Answer (score 3):

Someone please link the Regex HTML Parser question...

There is a reason HTML parsers exist, which is to parse HTML.

This solution is a bit long, but it is versatile and works for elements with classes, ids, etc:

```
<?php

function innerHTML($node) {
  $doc = new DOMDocument();

  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));
  }

  return $doc->saveHTML();
}

$string = "<ul>
<li> some content</li>
<li> some other content</li>
<li> some other other content.</li>
</ul>";

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($string);

$ul = $document->getElementsByTagName("ul");

foreach ($ul as $element) {
  print innerHTML($element);
}

?>
```

---

It seems like you don't need the tag names. Try this simpler code:

```
<?php

$string = "<ul>
<li> some content</li>
<li> some other content</li>
<li> some other other content.</li>
</ul>";

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($string);

$ul = $document->getElementsByTagName("li");

foreach ($ul as $element) {
  print $element->nodeValue;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I ultimated ended up using this for this particular problem. But I have faced this issue multiple times before.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.*?` rather than `.*` - it is lazy or non-greedy match and matches as little as possible.

Response to @CanSpice:

Of course regex is not suited for HTML. OP should try something like `<li>(?!.*<li>).*?</li>` depending on what he is doing. OR rather use a parser. I can only direct the OP one step at a time

Comment: What happens if he tries to parse `<li><ul><li>text</li></ul></li>`?

Comment: @CanSpice - Of course regex is not suited for HTML. OP should try something like `<li>(?!.*<li>).*?</li>` depending on what he is doing. OR rather use a parser. I can only direct the OP one step at a time

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the Regexp non-greedy

```
<li>(.*?)</li>
```

Comment: What happens if he tries to parse `<li><ul><li>text</li></ul></li>`?

Comment: It will stop feeding after the first </li> so it cannot match the complete outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are matching HTML text I would suggest atleast use `s` and `i` flags like this:

```
'~<li>(.*?)</li>~is'
```

- s is for DOTALL to make dot `.` match all the characters including new line
- i is for ignore case matching

Answer (score 0):

`<?php
$str = '<ul>
<li> some content</li>
<li> some other content</li>
<li> some other other content.</li>
</ul>';`

preg_match_all('/<li>([^<]+)</li>/i', $str, $r);
print_r($r[1]);
?>

Output:

```
`Array
(
    [0] =>  some content
    [1] =>  some other content
    [2] =>  some other other content.
)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = '<ul>'+
'<li> some content</li>'+
'<li> some other content</li>'+
'<li> some other other content.</li>'+
'</ul>'

a.split("<li>") 
gives
["<ul>", " some content</li>", " some other content</li>", " some other other content.</li></ul>"]
```

From there we can pick whatever we want.